Clone/Copy Physical Machine devices layout into proper domain.xml or equivalent
I have a physical machine, lets say its Dell R650, it have 2 ports for Embedded NIC, 4 ports of Integrated nic, two ssd disks in raid 1 in bays 1 and two on front panel, 2 hdd disks in raid 1 in bays 3 and 4  in front panel, another 2 ssd disks in raid 1 in bays 5 and 6 in front panel, and 2 hdd disks in raid 1 in bays 7 and 8 in front panel.
I would like to generate a domain.xml for libvirt, xl.cfg for xen, or any config file for any virtualization system like Virtualbox, maybe VMware, in a way that when i run the same system image on virtual machine as on physical one i get the same interface names on correct ports, and proper /dev/sdx identifiers for proper disks, i do not want to clone disk contents, only layout of devices / pci connections or whatever plays a role in assigning interface/device names, is there such software that can generate such config when run on physical machine?

Any physical-to-virtual (p2v) tool can generate a config file from a physical device, like virt-p2v for KVM/libvirt for example. If you do not want it to actually copy the data & create disk images of each hdd, then you can exclude those drives when configuring the p2v.
However, none of the tools (that I'm familiar with) will add the configuration for drives to a vm config file without copying the data as well. Those config files require a source path for the target vm's disk image(s) - a valid libvirt domain.xml contains something like this for example:
<devices>
  <disk type='file' snapshot='external'>
    <target dev='hda' bus='ide'/>
    <source file='/var/lib/xen/images/fv0' startupPolicy='optional'>

The config won't be valid if there's no disk image there. It also creates the correct IDE/SATA/SCSI bus type following the typical linux device naming conventions. Other P2V tools like vmware converter and its .vmx files behave in generally the same way.
Depending on how specific these configs need to be and how many you need to create, you might find it easiest to either add the disks manually, script it yourself, or just include the disks to make full use of the p2v clone tools.
